# vim completion deletes typed letters

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I've come to a vim completion behavior that is very annoying for me and I cannot figure out how to configure vim to behave differently.Maybe it is not possible at all.

Suppose I'm editing file with following content:

```
MyCompany2
MyCompanies
MyCompany3
```

Now I want to add another entry (say MyCompanyABC) so I type `My` and hit <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>, so now I have

> MyCompany2

Now I hit <kbd>backspace</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd> so I'm at

> MyCompanyA

No I decide to try completion again so I hit <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> and vim takes me back to

> My

So is there a way to make it so that the last step keeps what I already have?

**UPDATE:**

I gave the completion sequence wrong. The problem I describe appears if one first hits <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd>. Then in the above scenario you get and the rest as above.

> MyCompany3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't behave like this on my machine (Ubuntu 10.10, vim 7.2.330 here). If I do this:

- Open vim by typing `vi`
- Type the text you gave above

  ```
  MyCompany2
  MyCompanies
  MyCompany3
  ```
- Open a new line below
- Type "My"
- Press Ctrl-N
- Choose MyCompany2
- Backspace (get "MyCompany" after that)
- Type A (get "MyCompanyA")

Ctrl-N does nothing - as expected, status bar says: `-- Keyword completition (^N^P) Pattern not found`.

Is it possible you have some plugin that is changing the default behavior? You can also try `vi -u NONE` to check whether you have something in your `.vimrc` that is changing this behavior. Best if you have some other system to check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question - the problem appear only after first attempting the completion with Ctrl-P. Now I tried vim 7.0 on CentOs5 and vim 7.2 on Windows7

Comment: Yep, this indeed seems to be inconsistent. Try `Ctrl-E` after your `Ctrl-P` to abort completion, which will kinda be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to use Ctrl-N directly without hitting Ctrl-X beforehand? Ctrl-N will also search in all opened buffers.

Maybe hitting CTRL-X CTRL-N or CTRL-X CTRL-P will result in a more stable completion.